# PyQt5 Application shutting down when QFileDialog is closed

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

code:

```
def open_file(self):
    filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', expanduser("~"))
    try:
        with open(filename[0], 'r') as f:
            text = f.read()
            self.path = filename[0]
            self.textEdit.setPlainText(text)
            self.setWindowTitle(f'{filename[0]} - QtNotepad')

    except Exception as e:
        error = QDialog(str(e))
        error.show()
        pass
```

If I choose to close the file dialog using the top right corner X or the close button the application shuts down. I can't figure out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A canceled file dialog returns an empty string as first parameter; since `open()` expects a valid file path or object, it will raise a `FileNotFoundError` exception, since `''` is obviously not a valid file path.

In the exception you used a string as argument for the [`QDialog()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#QDialog) constructor, which is wrong since, like most widgets, it can only accept a *QWidget* as first positional argument (only *strictly* text based widgets accept a string).

The proper way to handle a canceled file dialog static method is to check if the path argument is empty. Then, if the file *does* exist but you want to show an error message if anything wrong happens in the `open` block, you should use a QMessageBox instead, as a basic QDialog is practically an empty widget.

```
def open_file(self):
    filename, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', expanduser("~"))
    if not filename:
        return
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            text = f.read()
            self.path = filename
            self.textEdit.setPlainText(text)
            self.setWindowTitle(f'{filename} - QtNotepad')

    except Exception as e:
        QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Error', 
            f'The following error occurred:\n{type(e)}: {e}')
        return
```

Whenever you get a crash, you must try to run your script in a terminal or prompt (using an IDE is not always enough) so that you can get the full traceback of the error which will probably explain why the program crashed.
Also, adding print statements of the exception right at the beginning of their handlers will help you understand the reason for those exceptions.

Comment: what does the underscore do when you are assigning the filename? Also thank very much for helping me.

Comment: @LukePitstick all file-related static methods of QFileDialog always return a tuple composed of the selected path and the file type filter. In python it's common convention to use the underscore for variables that are assigned but not used, but you can obviously use any valid variable name you wish. The important aspect is to assign the returned values to individual variables, in this way you don't have to always use the `[]` selector to get the first item of the tuple. PS: remember that if an answer solves your problem you should mark it as accepted by clicking the gray tick mark on its left.